# "is_logged_in" templatetag does not render

Tags: django, templatetags

for some reason, templatetags do not render in templates for django admin.

with this snippet from:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/?from=olddocs#shortcut-for-simple-tags

```
{% if is_logged_in %}Thanks for logging in!{% else %}Please log in.{% endif %}
```

when placed in admin index.html, if a user is logged in, it shows "Please log in"

same with templatetags, can not get any app ones to show, do anything. there is no error/they do not get processed either

Answer (score 5):

That's only an example, the `is_logged_in` variable is not actually defined in any templates unless you put it in the context.

If you added that line and got `Please log in.` it does mean that the tag is rendering.  If it fails the `if` and goes to the `else` it is clearly being run.  You need to find something in the template you can actually use for the `if` case, though.  I haven't messed with the admin templates in newforms-admin, but depending if they use RequestContext and on which ContextProcessors you have enabled - you might be able to say `{% if not request.user.is_anonymous %} ...` or something similar.

Comment: tried using custom templatetags examples on:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/
none seem to work, they do not show, nor are any errors

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this one:

request.user.is_authenticated

Right in the template and just worked as we wish!